# Dimensionality and value of $\mathbb{I}_A$ in Quantum operations

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-operation

I was checking this [question answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276053/trouble-with-operator-sum-representation-of-a-quantum-operation/276158) but I still can't get what is the value and dimension of $\mathbb{I}_A$ in this question and on the answer. Is it an identity matrix or some vector?

It also appears in the answer as $\mathbb{I}$ multiple times.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the identity operator on system $A$ so it has the same size as $\rho_A$. To convince yourself further of the solution it may be a good idea to do the calculation yourself with some small matrices. What may be confusing you is that whilst $I_A$ will be a square matrix, $I_A \otimes |0\rangle$ will not be. However, it will still have the correct dimensions in order to make the product $(I_A \otimes |0\rangle) \rho_A$ well defined.

Comment: So $I_A$ will be square matrix?[[1 0 ],[0, 1]] And also why did you write $\rho_{A}$ in subscript in you answer? +1 for answering

Comment: Yes, the identity operator is a square matrix. The $\rho_A$ was not a subscript, I've added some brackets to make this clearer.

Comment: square matrix and it is identity matrix. Right? I want to hear it . It is identity?

Comment: Yes, it is the identity.